# Nested Depth for BSON Documents

Tags: mongodb

Suppose we have this document of nested documents:

```
{
  _id:"12345678"
  field:{
        field:{
              field:{.....}
              }
        }
}
```

MongoDB [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#BSON-Document-Size) says:

> MongoDB supports no more than 100 levels of nesting for BSON
>   documents.

Could there perhaps have been a mistake in MongoDB documentation?
I was able to nest **147168** documents like the previous example when I got the error during the import.